# Extraction of src and value from html not working?

Tags: php, html

So the problem here is that when i use getElementById() it doesn't work. But, if i replace it with getElementsByTagName('img') it's perfectly fine.

How do i fix this problem, if possible?

(html codes are in file garden.php)Html:

```
<img id="head" src="images/flowers.png" value="blah">
```

(Php codes is in the head of the garden.php file)
Php:

```
<?
$html = file_get_contents('garden.php');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementById('head') as $tag) {

echo $tag->getAttribute('value'); // "prints" yellow
    echo "<br>";
echo $tag->getAttribute('src'); // prints images/flowers.png
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` doesn't return an array. IDs are unique, so it just returns a single element. Why do you need a loop for a single element?

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit the loop out. Is there a way to grab the contents of a specific img tag?

Comment: @user3121403, What do you want to grab exactly ?

Comment: Barmar answered the question, thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using a `foreach` loop. IDs are unique, so `getElementById` returns a `DOMElement`, not a `DOMNodeList`.

```
$tag = $dom->getElementById('head');
echo $tag->getAttribute('value') . '<br>' . $tag->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: @user3121403, as Barmar mentioned `getElementById` doesn't return an array, which was correct...you can see it is `getElementById` and not `getElementsById` (see there is no 's') which would give you an idea ;)